# Show field when date is more than a specified number of days ago?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm attempting to build a cognito form and would like to display a field only when the date selected in a preceding field is more than 3 years (1095 Days) ago.

Field A: Date of Issue of (Certificate)? Select Date
Field B: shows when Field A Date is greater than 1095 Days ago/3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Click Show This Field, When,

```
=DateTime.Today < FieldA.AddYears(3)
```

Make sure That FieldA is a Date